# Loop with gsub to replace a character through different columns stored in a vector

Tags: r, loops, gsub

This is my first question here.

I have a df (*us_census*). In some columns I wanna remove the percent symbol (%). The columns are defined as strings in the vector races. Any idea how to use a loop with mutate and gsub? Below code is not working.

```
races <- c('Hispanic', 'White', 'Black', 'Native', 'Asian', 'Pacific')
for (item in races){
  us_census <- mutate(us_census, get(item)=gsub('\\%','',get(item)))
}
```

I wanna avoid to use apply().
Is it mandatory to use a loop?
may use something different?
I wanted to avoid the long and traditional way written below

```
us_census <- us_census %>%
  mutate(Hispanic=gsub('\\%','',Hispanic),
         White=gsub('\\%','',White), Black=gsub('\\%','',Black), Native=gsub('\\%','',Native), Asian=gsub('\\%','',Asian), Pacific=gsub('\\%','',Pacific))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `for` loop, the `tidyverse` approach would be to specify the 'races' in `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
us_census <- us_census %>%
                 mutate_at(vars(races), ~ str_remove(., fixed('%')))
```

---

Regarding the OP's code, instead of `get`, we can use `:=` for assignment.  As `item` is a string, we can evaluate with `!!` on the lhs of `:=` while extracting the value of the column by converting the string to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`).  To make this faster, it would be better to specify `fixed = TRUE` along with the fact that if there is only a single instance of `%`, use `sub` instead of `gsub` (for global substitution)

```
library(dplyr)
for (item in races){
    us_census <- us_census %>%
                    mutate(!! item :=sub('%','', !! rlang::sym(item), fixed = TRUE))
  }
```

Also, another option is `str_replace` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
for (item in races){
    us_census <- us_census %>%
                    mutate(!! item :=str_remove(!! rlang::sym(item), fixed('%')))
  }
```

---